# Creating an Archive Macro Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

In this latest project the desire is to have a button & macro that will do the following:

When clicked the macro will copy all the data from the existing workbook & save it to another location. To create the copy of the workbook I will be using the following code below:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This code was sourced from - http://goo.gl/t7qOyB

Once the copy has been archived, the data in the existing workbook must then be removed leaving all the formatting behind. How can removing the data but keeping the formatting be achieved?

Comment: what data? clear cell values? it's unclear what you want to do. please give more details

Comment: My apologies mehow that was a detail I overlooked. I want to clear the cell values from all the sheets whilst leaving the formatting alone. There maybe a need to keep some cell data but this could be achieved by locking the sheets so that they are not able to be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.ClearContents()` property of `Cells` *Collection*

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

This code iterates through all sheets in the current workbook and deletes the values from cells keeping the formatting.

## Update!

If you wanted to clear only specific range on each sheet then

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1:B20").ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

This will clear only range `A1:B20` on each sheet.

Comment: Worked a treat. This was exactly what I needed. Thanks Mehow.

Comment: This is just out of curiosity more than anything. Could this code be modified to only clear a selected cell range? I.e. Range A2 : G44?